# Change color of Gridview row if it in the same date be white color and then gray

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i need to have three color on dynamic Gridview one white and the another is gray  but if it in the same date 
and if the previous date not found be red 
what i mean is :

```
Name        Checkin           Checkout              Branch 
450 10/6/2014 9:13:38 AM    10/6/2014 6:01:50 PM    branch0  white
450 10/7/2014 9:16:34 AM    10/7/2014 6:44:21 PM    branch0 gray
450 10/8/2014 9:11:53 AM                            branch0 white
450 10/8/2014 6:03:25 PM                            branch0 white
450 10/11/2014 9:17:33 AM   10/11/2014 6:29:16 PM   branch0 red
450 10/11/2014 4:50:42 PM                           branch0 red
450 10/12/2014 9:09:38 AM                           branch0 white
```

and that is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="602px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
                    SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Checkin" HeaderText="Checkin" 
                    SortExpression="Checkin" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Checkout" HeaderText="Checkout" 
                    SortExpression="Checkout" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineAlias" HeaderText="Branch" 
                    SortExpression="MachineAlias" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

and this is the code

```
Public Class WebForm2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

after i search i have this code

```
Dim found As Boolean
    Dim dt As DateTime
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Checkout")) Then
                dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Checkout")).Date


            End If

            If e.Row.RowIndex > 0 And found = False Then
                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
            found = Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Checkout"))
        End If
    End Sub
```

but it give my error

[image: Error]

when i try the code from MR @Zack i have this error

[image: Eroor3]

Comment: Pretty sure you can use the RowDataBound event to compare the two columns against each other and highlight them when there is a match in the date. You would need to format the data coming from the cell to mm/dd/yyyy and drop the time though in order for it to be an exact match. I'd give you an example but I'm not sitting at a computer with a compiler and don't want to give you ugly code. If you google it though you should be able to find something on it.

Comment: The error line is because it needs to be e.Row.RowType and you just have an 'R' in the middle of it. It's also handling GridView1.DataBinding and needs to be GridView1.RowDataBound

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles        GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim arg1 As Date = Date.Parse(e.Row.Cells(1).Text)
        Dim arg2 As Date = Date.Parse(iif(isDate(e.Row.Cells(2).Text),e.Row.Cells(2).Text,"1/1/1900"))

        If arg1 = arg2 Then
            e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: first let me thank you and i edit my post for you i have an error and are make sure if i try this code i will have the three color W and G and R

Comment: Try changing to my suggestion above, sorry if the syntax is jacked up I'm doing this from memory at the moment...